# Generate Alphanumeric Customer ID

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on migrating data out of a legacy system.  To accommodate our new system proper customer ID's need to be generated.  I'm looking for a way to generate unique alphanumeric  ID's based in part on the customer's last name.  The convention to be used is the first 3 letters of the customers last name followed by a 3 digit identifier.  For example:

```
Smith, John = SMI001
Smith, Robert = SMI002
Jones, David = JON001
```

The new system will auto-generate new customers id's going forward, I just need a script to run once against the database I have no idea where to even begin.  Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(LastName NVARCHAR(50), FirstName NVARCHAR(50), ID NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Table(LastName, FirstName) VALUES 
('Smith', 'John'),('Smith', 'Robert'),('Jones', 'David'),('Smith', 'John'),
('Smith', 'John'),('Smith', 'Robert'),('Jones', 'David'),('Smith', 'John'),
('Smith', 'John'),('Smith', 'Robert'),('Jones', 'David'),('Smith', 'John'),
('Smith', 'John'),('Smith', 'Robert'),('Jones', 'David'),('Smith', 'John')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName,
       UPPER(LEFT(LastName, 3)) + LEFT('000', LEN(ROW_NUMBER()
                   OVER (PARTITION BY  LEFT(LastName, 3)ORDER BY LEFT(LastName, 3)) )+1)
      +  CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  
               LEFT(LastName, 3)ORDER BY LEFT(LastName, 3))  AS NVARCHAR(1000)) AS ID
FROM @Table
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ LastName ║ FirstName ║    ID    ║
╠══════════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON001   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON002   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON003   ║
║ Jones    ║ David     ║ JON004   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI001   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI002   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI003   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI004   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI005   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI006   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI007   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI008   ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI009   ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI00010 ║
║ Smith    ║ John      ║ SMI00011 ║
║ Smith    ║ Robert    ║ SMI00012 ║
╚══════════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query demonstrating how to generate such IDs:

```
SELECT  FirstName,
        LastName,
        Code = UPPER(LEFT(LastName, 3)) 
                + RIGHT('000' 
                    + CAST(
                        Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY LastName 
                                            ORDER BY FirstName) 
                        AS NVARCHAR(3))
                    , 3)
FROM    [Table1]
```